# Generating a random value when calling an enum

Tags: java, random, enums

I'm making an app for generating fractals and I'm stuck on one thing. The program asks for two colors: one for the background, and one for the fractal. So I made an enum of colors:

```
public class Property {
    public enum Color {

        WHITE(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255).getRGB()),
        BLACK(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0).getRGB()),
        BLUE(new java.awt.Color(110, 124, 255).getRGB()),
        GREEN(new java.awt.Color(121, 206, 30).getRGB()),
        RED(new java.awt.Color(255, 58, 36).getRGB()),
        YELLOW(new java.awt.Color(254, 255, 57).getRGB()),
        ORANGE(new java.awt.Color(255, 133, 46).getRGB()),
        PURPLE(new java.awt.Color(206, 27, 255).getRGB()),
        PINK(new java.awt.Color(255, 40, 166).getRGB()),
        RANDOM(Utils.randomColor()),

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name().toLowerCase();
        }

        private int color;

        Color(int color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public int getRGB() {
            return this.color;
        }
    }
}
```

The `randomColor()` method looks like this:

```
public class Utils {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static int randomColor() {
        int r = RANDOM.nextInt(256);
        int g = RANDOM.nextInt(256);
        int b = RANDOM.nextInt(256);
        return new java.awt.Color(r, g, b).getRGB();
    }
}
```

But I noticed that the random color is actually created only once, and so both colors are the same which obviously is not a desired output. How can I make this generate two different colors each time the `Property.Color.RANDOM` is called?

Comment: Do you want `Property.Color.RANDOM. getRGB` to return the same value each time? If not, the getRGB method for the random instance needs to be overridden to return `Utils.random color()`.  `RANDOM (...){@Override public int getRGB(){...}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the `Color` enum is initialized, `RANDOM` will be one specific color - it may be different from execution to execution, but in a single run, it will stay fixed.

What you want is to generate a new Color every time you use `RANDOM`. (At least that's how I understood it) One way to do this is using a constant-specific enum body:

```
public enum Color {
    //...
    RANDOM(0) {
        @Override
        public int getRGB() {
            return Utils.randomColor();
        }
    };

    //...
}
```

---

This has its own problems. For example, you probably want to generate multiple random colors, each of which remains constant. Otherwise, each time you use the color, you get a new one. To avoid this, the only way is really not to use an enum at all, at least not exclusively. Basically, the solution would be to do what `java.awt.Color` already does: a simple class that you can create arbitrary instances of, and `public static final` constants that enumerate some predefined colors.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the problem I had. I ended up refactoring the code, but thank you for your help. I didn't know enums can work like that.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers will work, but in Java 8 there's an even nicer way to do it. Have each enum be initialized not with its color, but an [`IntSupplier<Color>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html).

```
public class Property {
    ...
    Property(IntSupplier rgbSupplier) {
        this.rgbSupplier = rgbSupplier;
    }

    Property(int rgb) {  // convenience constructor
        this(() -> rgb); // delegate to constructor above
    }

    public int getRGB() {
        return rgbSupplier.getAsInt();
    }
    ...
}
```

For most of your colors, the construction is the same; but for the random one, you supply a method reference:

```
    ...
    PINK(new java.awt.Color(255, 40, 166).getRGB()),
    RANDOM(Utils::randomColor),
    ...
```

In English, what this is doing is constructing each enum not with a specific value, but with an `IntSupplier` that says "get me the value." The "standard" types are each constructed with an `IntSupplier` that always returns the provided value (`() -> rgb`), but the random one is constructed with an `IntSupplier` that invokes `Utils.randomColor()`.

Comment: Wow, lambda expressions look so ugly. These double colons make me cringe. I'll get to it sometime later, still got a long way ahead of me.

Comment: Ugly is in the eye of the beholder :) But if you don't like the method reference (the double colon), an equivalent lambda would be `RANDOM( () -> Utils.randomColor() )`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this simply redefine the `getRGB()` method for `RANDOM` enum value. Here's the whole code:

```
public class Property {
    public enum Color {

        WHITE(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255).getRGB()),
        BLACK(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0).getRGB()),
        BLUE(new java.awt.Color(110, 124, 255).getRGB()),
        GREEN(new java.awt.Color(121, 206, 30).getRGB()),
        RED(new java.awt.Color(255, 58, 36).getRGB()),
        YELLOW(new java.awt.Color(254, 255, 57).getRGB()),
        ORANGE(new java.awt.Color(255, 133, 46).getRGB()),
        PURPLE(new java.awt.Color(206, 27, 255).getRGB()),
        PINK(new java.awt.Color(255, 40, 166).getRGB()),
        RANDOM(0) {
            @Override
            public int getRGB() {
                return Utils.randomColor();
            }
        };

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name().toLowerCase();
        }

        private int color;

        Color(int color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public int getRGB() {
            return this.color;
        }
    }
}
```

It's possible for individual enum values to override method implementations like it's done in the subclasses. Here we use this for `RANDOM` value to return the new random color every time (ignoring the `color` field, it's just set to 0).

Answer (score 0):

enum is going to be initializes only once. Code above RANDOM(Utils.randomColor()) is not a method but a value of enum. It is not going to call every time you are accessing RANDOM. As call randomColor() method to generate random color rather than assigning to RANDOM enum.